# How to use OR condition in rivetsJS

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

How to use OR condition in rivetsJS while binding it in html dom. The below code does not work for me while using rivets. It works when i use a single condition

```
<div rv-class-highlight="view.year || view.month">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a formatter

```
rivets.formatters.or = function(value, args) {
  return value || args;
};
```

And then

```
<div rv-class-highlight="view.year | or view.month">
</div>
```